# Cannot deploy go app on Heroku. Push rejected, failed to compile Go app

Tags: go, heroku

```
git push heroku master

Enumerating objects: 1071, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1071/1071), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1010/1010), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1062/1062), 38.87 MiB | 1.50 MiB/s, done.
Total 1062 (delta 332), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/go
remote: -----> Go app detected
remote: -----> Fetching stdlib.sh.v8... done
remote: -----> 
remote:        Detected go modules via go.mod
remote: -----> 
remote:        Detected Module Name: github.com/IDarar/herokutest
remote: -----> 
remote: -----> Using go1.16.1
remote: -----> Determining packages to install
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Go app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to herokutest.
remote: 
To ssh://heroku.com/herokutest.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@heroku.com/herokutest.git'
```

I've already deployed this app on heroku, and now trying to add there a postgresql DB. Maybe problem in the driver, but I don't think that it is issue, because I can compile this app locally and there are no any problems. And even if I remove all code with connecting to db I get the exact same log.

Maybe also the go version cause fail because it is declared in go.mod as

```
// +heroku goVersion go1.16
```

but in log there is `remote: -----> Using go1.16.1`

`go.mod` file

```
module github.com/IDarar/herokutest

// +heroku goVersion go1.16
go 1.16

require (
    github.com/asaskevich/govalidator v0.0.0-20210307081110-f21760c49a8d // indirect
    github.com/disintegration/imaging v1.6.2
    github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation v3.6.0+incompatible
    github.com/gorilla/mux v1.8.0
    github.com/gorilla/sessions v1.2.1
    github.com/ivanmrchk/gravatar v0.0.0-20170201231613-48cf3dfff561
    github.com/jackc/pgproto3/v2 v2.0.7 // indirect
    github.com/jinzhu/now v1.1.2 // indirect
    github.com/lib/pq v1.10.0 // indirect
    github.com/rs/cors v1.7.0
    github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.8.1
    github.com/stretchr/testify v1.7.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20210322153248-0c34fe9e7dc2
    golang.org/x/image v0.0.0-20210220032944-ac19c3e999fb // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20210320140829-1e4c9ba3b0c4 // indirect
    golang.org/x/text v0.3.5 // indirect
    golang.org/x/xerrors v0.0.0-20200804184101-5ec99f83aff1 // indirect
    gorm.io/driver/postgres v1.0.8
    gorm.io/gorm v1.21.4
)
```

---

Well, I created a new app on Heroku and pushed the exact same code and it works now. But it is still interesting what caused fail on pushing

Comment: Can you post contents of `go.mod` file?

Comment: @blami Updated in question